# Change string to float from csv list

Tags: python, for-loop

how can I convert the numbers in this list to floats? I keep getting the ValueError because it gets stuck on the strings that aren't numbers. At the bottom my code

This is the out put I get now:

```
['\ufeff', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood']
['appel', '3', '4', '0', '0']
['gaar', '2', '2', '0', '1']
['schotel', '2', '4', '0', '0']
['amandel', '0', '0', '4', '0']
['deeg', '1', '0', '2', '5']
['brood', '0', '0', '0', '1']
['suiker', '0', '2', '2', '0']
```

Ad this is what I need

```
    [['', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood'],
    ['appel', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['gaar', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ['schotel', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ['amandel', 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
    ['deeg', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0],
    ['brood', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ['suiker', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]]
```

Thanks

```
import csv
csv_file = open("recepten.csv")
recepten = csv.reader(csv_file)

for line in recepten:
    for item in line:
        x = item.split(";")
        for a in item:
           float(a)
print(x)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: @funnydman The variable `x` will still be accessible since Python doesn't have any block scope in for loops

Comment: Always share the entire error message. Where is the [mcve]? What's the point of using the csv module if you're just going to split the data yourself? _I keep getting the ValueError because it gets stuck on the strings that aren't numbers._ You seem to know exactly what the issue is, so what is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem occurs whenever your code tries to convert a not a number string to float. You should catch the error using try/except to explain what should happen whenever a not a number string is found.

I also changed few steps in your looping understanding that you are opening a csv file, not using csv lib. list_of_lists already contains the results you need.

```
csv_file = open("recepten.csv")


list_of_lists = []

for line in csv_file:
    x = line.split(";")
    for i in range(len(x)):
       try:
           x[i] = float(x[i]) #changing your list x
       except ValueError:
           pass #not converting strings
    list_of_lists.append(x)
print(list_of_lists)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost solves it, except, why does it print \ufeff and brood\n in the first list?

[['\ufeff', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood\n'], ['appel', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['gaar', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0], ['schotel', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['amandel', 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0], ['deeg', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0], ['brood', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], ['suiker', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]]

Comment: _I also changed few steps in your looping understanding that you are opening a csv file, not using csv lib._ They are using the csv library though, no? Am I misunderstanding what you were trying to say? Why aren't you using a context manager for that file object? Why are you using a `for ... in range()` loop instead of a `for ... in ...` loop?

Comment: You must iterate the list using positions reference in order to be able to change it. If not, it is just a copy of the objected in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you know which columns need to be floats vs strings you could do something like this:

```py
clean_data = [] # Where you'll be storing the data

for row in raw_data:
    clean_data.append([]) # Add a new row to the clean data list

    first_column_value = row[0] # Get the first value that we know is a string
    clean_data[-1].append(first_column_value) # Add it to the last row on the list

    for col in row[1:]: # Loop through the rest of the values in the row
        clean_data[-1].append(float(col)) # Convert them to floats and add them

print(clean_data)
```

But also, if you don't know if a value is going to be a string or a float you could do something like this:

```py
clean_data = [] # Where you'll be storing the data

for row in raw_data:
    clean_data.append([]) # Add a new row to the clean data list

    for col in row:
        try: # Try to convert to a float
            val = float(col)
        except ValueError: # If you get a ValueError, keep it a string
            val = col

        clean_data[-1].append(val) # Add it to the clean_data

print(clean_data)
```